# Sum values in nested documents based on nested term aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I insert this data into elasticsearch:

```
{ "timestamp" : "2015-01-15T01:00:00", 
  "jobs" : [ 
    { "name" : "job1", "duration" : 33432 }, 
    { "name" : "job2", "duration" : 7543 } 
  ] 
}
```

I'm trying to graph this data in Kibana so that I get a bar that shows the total sum of all durations and the individual job durations separately as a split color on the same bar.

I have created a map for the index that says that the jobs field is a nested document and that it should index jobs.name and jobs.duration so that Elasticsearch doesn't flat out the data and loses the relation between the two.

In Kibana I've created:

```
Y-Axis: Sum for jobs.duration
X-Axis: Datehistogram
X-Axis: Split-bar on term jobs.name
```

But it just sums up all the jobs for both terms, so the table is showing two rows, one for job1 and one for job2 but they are both showing the sum of duration for both jobs times two (it doubles the sum). I want the row for with the term job1 to show just the duration of job1 and the same for job2.

Thanks.